# Asymptotic normality - It is reasonable to solve example 3.8 without computer?

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, normal-distribution

I got a question about example 3.8 from the following link on page 34:

https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.j.k.kleijn/AsympStat-LecNotes2010.pdf

What I try to do is showing the asymptotic normality claimed at this example, showable by theorem 3.7. With a computer, e.g. wolframalpha, it is doable to determine whether the derivative $\phi'_{\alpha,\beta}$ is regular or not. At an exam however we may only use paper and pencil, so I wonder if there is a trick to solve it by hand or that this cannot be a reasonable exam-question.

The matrix $\phi'_{\alpha,\beta}$ is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}\begin{pmatrix} \beta & 
\alpha \\ \frac{(\alpha+\beta+1)(\alpha+\beta)(2\alpha+1)-(\alpha+1)\alpha(2\alpha+2\beta+1)}{(\alpha+\beta+1)^2} & \frac{-(\alpha+1)\alpha(2\alpha+2\beta+1)}{(\alpha+\beta+1)^2}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then I hope the determinant is not equal to zero, because that is one condition for theorem 3.7 for asymptotic normality. Of course the $(\alpha+\beta+1)^2$ will cancel while calculating the determinant, but this is it.

Does anyone have an answer like "You can do this by hand as follows..." or "This is indeed not reasonable to do by hand only" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could note that the function in question 3.8 is the composition of two somewhat simpler functions: $(\alpha,\beta)\mapsto(\alpha/(\alpha+\beta), (\alpha+1)/(\alpha+\beta+1))$ and $(u,v)\mapsto (u,uv)$, for which the regularity checks are easier by hand.

Answer (score 2):

It's the former. As was hinted at in the example, you can derive an explicit formula to express $\theta=(\alpha,\beta)$ by $(\overline{X_n},\overline{X^2_n})$: your equations are
$$\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}=\overline{X_n}, \quad\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)}{(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha+\beta+1)}=\overline{X^2_n},$$ and you can convert that to the linear system 
\begin{align}
(1-\overline{X_n})\alpha-\overline{X_n}\beta&=0\\
(\overline{X_n}-\overline{X^2_n})\alpha-\overline{X^2_n}\beta&=\overline{X^2_n}-\overline{X_n}
\end{align} 
with the determinant of the coefficient matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1-\overline{X_n} & 
-\overline{X_n}\\ \overline{X_n}-\overline{X^2_n} & -\overline{X^2_n}
 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
being equal to $\overline{X^2_n}-\overline{X_n}^2>0$, i.e. it's a rational function with non-vanishing denominator. The $e'^{-1}_{\theta_0}$ (don't we love those notations?) in the theorem is the derivative of this inverse map, so it is obviously continuous.